# Prove that if $D^kf=0$ then $f$ is polynomial

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ an open connected set and let $f:E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a $k+1$ times differentiable function such that $D^kf=0$. Show that $f$ is a polynomial in $x_1,...,x_n$ at a degree of at most $k$.

---

For any $\pi\in\{1,...,n\}^n$ we're given that $\frac{\partial^{k+1}f}{\partial x_{\pi (1)}...\partial x_{\pi (k+1)}}=0$. Thus $\frac{\partial^{k}f}{\partial x_{\pi (1)}...\partial x_{\pi(k)}}=c_k$ and by induction $f=\partial^0 f=x_{\pi(1)}(x_{\pi(2)}(...(x_{\pi(k)}c_k+c_{k-1})...)+c_1)+c_0$ for some $c_i\in\mathbb{R}, \forall 1\leq i \leq n$. I feel that this proof doesn't hold but I don't know where is the mistake and what is the right way. Thanks

Comment: Taylor series might help?

Comment: Your integration is false. I mean, for instance if $f(x,y)$ a function in two variables and $d^2 /dx dy f(x,y)=0$ then $d/dx f(x,y)= c(x)$ this is a function of $x$ and not just a constant. I think a proof by induction is more appropriate here.

Comment: You should not bring permutations into the game. The variable $k$ counting the number of differentiations is independent of the number $n$ of variables $x_i$.

Comment: Such an $f$ is analytical and its series is finite...

Comment: @Federico why $f$ is analytical or as you claim, entire?

Comment: @WillM. If $D^kf=0$, then $f$ is in fact $C^\infty$. The derivatives are definitely $0$, so the radius of convergence is $\infty$. I'm not saying that this is the way to go, though... The *reasonable* proof is much more elementary, using Taylor.

Comment: I am baffled, the function is of several variables and we are in the real domain. Not obvious at all, while I do believe is true, the function is analytic.

Comment: Do you agree that the function is indeed $C^\infty$?

Comment: Yes. But $C^\infty$ in the real domain does not mean analytic. The function $x \mapsto e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$ for $x \neq 0$ and $0$ at zero is $C^\infty$ and its Taylor series has radius of convergence zero.

Comment: Yes but here the radius of convergence is infinite. Anyway, I have to go and this is futile because this exercise is a consequence of Taylor with explicit remainder term

Comment: Did you read the question? The function is defined on a set $\mathrm{E}$ which is open and connected only.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Derivation_for_the_remainder_of_multivariate_Taylor_polynomials

Comment: Define a function $\phi$ to be the first $k$ terms of the Taylor series. Show that $f-\phi $ is zero on every line (so it is a one dimensional problem).

Comment: @copper.hat it would remain to show a function that is locally a polynomial of degree $k$ is a polynomial of degree $k.$

Comment: @WillM.: Finally got some time; I have elaborated my comments in an answer below (which is just a long winded version of my previous comment).

Answer (score 2):

**Abridged solution.** Proceed by induction on $k.$ The case $k = 1$ is very standard and often appears in books. The aim is to show $f$ is constant. It goes like this, consider a "base point" $a \in E$ and the set $\mathrm{X}$ of points in $x \in \mathrm{E}$ such that $f(x)=f(a).$ Then $\mathrm{X}$ is closed in $\mathrm{E}$ as $f$ is continuous. Now, $\mathrm{X}$ is also open in $\mathrm{E}$ for if $x \in \mathrm{X}$ then there is a small enough ball centred at $x$ contained in $\mathrm{E}$ and for such ball the mean value theorem (applied to the line segment between $x$ and another point in the ball) gives that $f$ is constant in such ball, so such ball is subset of $\mathrm{X}$ and then $\mathrm{X}$ is open as claimed. Being $\mathrm{E}$ connected, $\mathrm{X} = \mathrm{E}$ and the base case $k = 1$ is proved.

For the general case, assume $f$ satisfies $f^{(k+1)}=0$ on $\mathrm{E}.$ The case $k = 1$ shows that $f^{(k)}$ is a constant $k$-linear function on $\mathrm{E},$ call it $M.$ We show that $\varphi:x \mapsto f(x) - \dfrac{1}{k!}M(x, \ldots, x)$ satisfies $\varphi^{(k)}=0$ on $\mathrm{E}$ and hence, by induction, $\varphi$ is a polynomial function of degree $\leq k-1$ and then $f$ is a polynomial function of degree $\leq k.$ By standard results about derivatives of multilinear functions and the chain rule, we get at once that $\varphi^{(k)}=f^{(k)}-\dfrac{1}{k!} k!M = 0.$ Q.E.D.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f$ is smooth since if $D^k f = 0$ then $D^l f = 0$ for $ l \ge k$.

Fix some $x_0 \in E$, and suppose $C$ is an open convex set containing $x_0$ and contained in $E$. Then Taylor's theorem shows that if $y \in C$ then we 
have  $f(y) = \sum_{|\alpha| \le k-1} {1 \over \alpha !} D^\alpha f(x_0) (y-x_0)^\alpha$.

Let $p(y) = \sum_{|\alpha| \le k-1} {1 \over \alpha !} D^\alpha f(x_0) (y-x_0)^\alpha$ be the polynomial, note that $p$ is defined everywhere and has maximum degree $k-1$. We wish to show that
$f=p$ on $E$.

As an aside, note that if $q$ is a polynomial and $q(x) = 0$ for $x$ in some open set then $q=0$.

Pick some $x_n\in E$ and note that since $E$ is open and connected there are $x_k \in E$ such that the straight line curve $x_0 \to x_1 \to \cdots \to x_n$ is contained
in $E$.

Since the segment $[x_0,x_1] \subset E$, there is some open convex set $C_1$ such that
$[x_0,x_1] \subset C_1 \subset E$ and we have $f=p$ on $C_1$.

Now let $p'$ be the Taylor expansion based at $x_1$. As above, there is some open
convex set with $[x_1,x_2] \subset C_2 \subset E$ and we have $f=p'$ on $C_2$.

Since $x_1 \in C_1 \cap C_2$, we see that $p=p'$ on an open set, and hence $p'=p$ everywhere.

It is clear that we can repeat this process to  see that $f(x_n) = p(x_n)$.

Since $x_n \in E$ was arbitrary, we see that $f=p$ on $E$.

Comment: The first claim about Taylor's theorem expansion is not true (did you miss an integral remainder?) It is true when $f$ is a polynomial of degree $\leq k-1$ essentially by definition, your RHS is exactly a polynomial of degree $\leq k -1,$ which is exactly what we want to prove.

Comment: @WillM. The integral form of Taylor's theorem gives $f(y) =  \sum_{|\alpha| \le k-1} {1 \over \alpha !} D^\alpha f(x_0) (y-x_0)^\alpha + \sum_{|\alpha| =k} {k \over \alpha!} \int_0^1 (1-t)^{k-1}D^\alpha f(x_0+t(y-x))dt$, and since $D^k f = 0$ we get the desired result.

Comment: @WillM. Do you still maintain that the first statement is not true? If so, could you elaborate please?

Comment: No, I get your solution now. Thanks for clarifying. It was a bit fishy first, like I was wondering if you were assuming the result.

Answer (score -2):

Another alternative proof (which I guess is worng as well because I don't use the fact that $E$ is open and connected):

From Taylor's formula we know that
$$
\\  f(x_1,...,x_n)=\sum_{i_1=1}^\infty ...\sum_{i_n=1}^\infty \frac{(x_1-a_1)^{i_1}\cdot...\cdot(x_n-a_n)^{i_n}}{i_1!\cdot...\cdot i_n!}\cdot\frac{\partial ^{i_1+...+i_n}f}{\partial x_1^{i_1}...\partial x_n^{i_n}}(a_1,...,a_n) \
$$
Let $0\leq i_1,...,i_n\leq k$. If $\sum_{j=1}^n i_j>k$ then $\frac{\partial ^{i_1+...+i_n}f}{\partial x_1^{i_1}...\partial x_n^{i_n}}(a)=0$. Otherwise, $\frac{(x_1-a_1)^{i_1}\cdot...\cdot(x_n-a_n)^{i_n}}{i_1!\cdot...\cdot i_n!}$ is polynom of a degree at most $k$, and $\frac{\partial ^{i_1+...+i_n}f}{\partial x_1^{i_1}...\partial x_n^{i_n}}(a_1,...,a_n)$ is a **constant** linear tranformation. Thus $f(x_1,...,x_n)$ is a polynom of degree at most $k$.

Comment: Why $f$ is analytic?

Comment: I don't find the answre, why is it really? @WillM.

Comment: I can only prove it is by well, showing it is a polynomial. This phenomenon of "a function is a polynomial provided _one_ of its higher derivatives is zero identically" holds true in Banach spaces. As the proof I wrote shows.